# Android hashmap returns null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I'm trying to send a hashmap between activities, but it is always null.

Sending code :

```
public HashMap <Integer, Integer> pickedPick = new HashMap <>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CharPick.class);
intent.putExtra("hashMap", pickedPick);
startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving code :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
pickedPick = (HashMap <Integer, Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Where I use it and get the NPE before trying to send it back :

```
if (pickedPick != null && pickedPick.keySet().contains(clicked)){
    pickedPick.remove(clicked);
    pickedPick.put(clicked, picked);
} else if (pickedPick != null) { 
    pickedPick.put(clicked, picked);
}
intent.putExtra("hashMap", pickedPick);
startActivity(intent);
```

That's the only place where we're adding data in the hashmap and it doesn't work, because the hashmap is always considered null. I have no idea what causes it to stay null.

Comment: You can avoid the NPE if you break your if statement into two nested ones: `if (pickedPick != null) { if (pickedPick.keySet().contains(clicked) { ... } else { ... } }`

Comment: @Karakuri It does indeed fix the NPE, but the issue is that it just doesn't add the data in the hashmap. And that's the only place where we add data in it

Comment: Where are you trying to read the `pickedPick` HashMap? In which function? (onCreate, onResume, onNewIntent) - Check if the intent actually contains data.

Comment: @damian I read it in 2 different onCreate functions, and sends it in 2 different onClick functions (I send data and must keep it between 2 different activities, via buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement gets executed only when pickedPick object is null. So you are getting the NPE.

Comment: I've tried putting pickedPick != null in the else if too, but then it just does nothing, because it is null anyway :/